# Any way to do a weather screensaver for Linux or Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, linux, screensaver, lock-screen

I have a media computer we have in our shop connected to a 32" screen that we use to play music. Since it is in a public view area, I would like it to be set to "lock on resume" and have a **forecast or weather screensaver** of some kind showing.

I'm fairly new to Linux but have always thought it was supposed to be highly customizable.

It is a Windows 7 PC that I have dual booted with Linux mint 17 cinnamon, but I could use any version of Linux. Or even if it was way easier I could boot back to windows 7 and use that.

Does anyone know of an application that could do this in any version of Linux, or even possibly windows 7?

Comment: Win: A lock screen can only be a picture, there is no "live information" ability - for security reasons. I would suggest you have the computer in the public area but remove all input devices (cover USB ports too) so that you can keep the machine logged in and run whatever application you use for your information, without fear of user interaction. You could then plug in a keyboard/mouse when you (the admin) need to administer the machine (or even VNC to it across the network). Ideally, though, only have the monitor in the public area. Keep the PC locked away.

Comment: @BigChris Thanks for the input. I didn't think of this, and do to this computer not needing to be super secure and the fact it has a wireless keyboard/mouse near my office, this is very doable. I did have a weather screensaver in windows 7 that was supposedly live if I paid for it, so figured maybe there was something similar in Linux is all. But if not, this solution can work.

Comment: A simple hand-made solution for Linux: install `xtrlock`, open a web browser window fullscreen with your favorite weather page (or build one yourself), then press `Alt-F2` and start `xtrlock`. The cursor turns into a lock and you have to type in your password to exit locking and `xtrlock`. There are also some solutions to use a webpage as an xscreensaver module to be found on the Web.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using a browser in "Kiosk mode" is what you are looking for? For example to set weatherunderground to look like a screensaver, enter this in the windows start run menu:

```
iexplore -k page
```

For example:

```
iexplore -k http://www.wunderground.com/q/zmw:46201.1.99999
```

To exit kiosk mode, Alt-F4.

More info on kiosk mode for [IE is here.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154780)

Comment: This would work, but would need to be "logged in" as a user. The user would still need to prevent user interaction with mouse and keyboard or plugging their own devices in (block USB etc.)...

Comment: I may look into a Linux or windows kiosk solution sometime when I have more time to play as that would probably be ideal for this PC. (Although I need to use chrome for about 4 extensions I need) For now though, I have xtrlock in Linux going with an auto refresh extension in chrome. It feels like a hack to use, but for now it's accomplishing pretty close to what I want. I do appreciate the thoughts though as I will be looking into a better more permanent fix here in time.